# Joomla Smart Search - Get Parent Category Alias

Tags: php, search, joomla

I have already added an image to the `default_results.php`. (thanks to help found here)

I would like to dynamically add a class to the `li` in the `default_results.php`

But I am kind of at a loss.

The class to be pulled from the parent category (alias) of the li result

I have successfully done this for the tags (`default_item.php`) by adding:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$id = $item->core_catid;
$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.parent_id FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$id'");
$parent_category_id = $db->loadResult();
$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.alias FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$parent_category_id'");
$parent_category_title = $db->loadResult();
?>
```

under

```
<?php foreach ($items as $i => $item) : ?>
```

and adding

```
tag-class-<?php if($parent_category_title != 'ROOT'){
 echo ''.$parent_category_title.'';
}
?>
```

to

```
<li class="cat-list-row<?php echo $i % 2; ?> clearfix >
```

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Hi Cathy! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).